# Output to two different consoles using python

Tags: python, terminal, console, output

I am writing a script and I have two different kinds of output, say Op1 and Op2. I want to output Op1 to the terminal where the python process was called from while Op2 should be dumped to a different terminal instance. Can I do that?

Even if the answer is Linux-specific it's okay, I need a temporary solution.

Comment: try dumping it on a text file instead

Comment: If it helps - just print the output of your script normally and pipe it through the [tee](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/utee.htm) command that will fork your script's output into multiple out streams.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make the Python script write to a file, or pipe its output to a file `python script.py >> output.log`, then you can `tail` the file with `-f` which makes it continuously update the view on your console.

### Example snippet

```
# logmaker.py
import time
import datetime

buffer_size = 0 # This makes it so changes appear without buffering
with open('output.log', 'a', buffer_size) as f:
    while(True):
        f.write('{}\n'.format(datetime.datetime.now()))
        time.sleep(1)
```

Run that file

```
python logmaker.py
```

Then in one or more consoles do

```
tail -f output.log
```

or `less` if you prefer

```
less +F output.log
```

You should get a continuous update like this

```
2016-07-06 10:52:44.997416
2016-07-06 10:52:45.998544
2016-07-06 10:52:46.999697
```

Comment: Snippet helped! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some common solutions in Linux.

To achieve this, you usually need two programs.

`File i/o + Loop`:

1. main program + file writer (print Op1 and write Op2 into file A)
2. file reader (keep fetching A file until it be modified and print the content of file A)

`Socket (pipe)`:

1. main program + sender (print Op1 and send Op2 to a specific socket)
2. receiver (listen a specific socket and print Op2 while receiving things)

`File i/o + Signal`:

1. main program + file writer + signal sender (print Op1 and write Op2 into file A and send signal to the daemon receiver)
2. signal receiver (halt until receiving signal and print the content of file A)

---

By the way, I suppose that your requirement does not need to write any daemon program because you have certainly two consoles.

Additionally, I am pretty sure that printing on specific console is achievable.

---

Example of second solution [Socket]

```
# print1.py (your main program)
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  
sock.connect(('localhost', 8001))  
Op1 = 'Op1'
Op2 = 'Op2'
print Op1 
sock.send(Op2)  
sock.close()
```

Steps

```
// a. console 2: listen 8001 port
// Luckily, nc(netcat) is enough to finish this without writing any code.
$ nc -l 8001

// b. console 1: run your main program
$ python print1.py
Op1

// c. console 2
Op2
```

Answer (score 1):

Following up on Kir's response [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38219807/8543847), as I am working on something similar, I further modified the script using threading so that the console listening is launched directly from the script, rather than having to be launched by hand. Hope it helps.

```
import subprocess
import threading
import socket
import time

def listenproc():
 monitorshell = subprocess.Popen("mate-terminal --command=\"nc -l 8001\"",shell=True)

def printproc():
 print("Local message")
 time.sleep(5) # delay sending of message making sure port is listening
 sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
 sock.connect(('localhost', 8001))
 sock.send("Sent message")
 time.sleep(5)
 sock.close()

listenthread = threading.Thread(name="Listen", target=listenproc, args=())
printhread = threading.Thread(name="Print", target=printproc, args=())

listenthread.start()
printhread.start()
listenthread.join()
printhread.join()
```

Comment: osbornere your solution looks very intriguing & I'm still trying to understand it.
> 'mate-terminal' is not recognized as an internal or external command, <

Comment: what is "mate-terminal" ?

Comment: I'm running python 3.7.1 w/ Windows 64

Comment: mate-terminal is the terminal of MATE desktop environment (https://mate-desktop.org/).

Some time has passed since I implemented this and I do not recall whether I used mate-terminal due to a specific reason or just because MATE was already installed on the machine I was working on though.