# Display print() separated from input() in python running in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I have an application on Python in which I need to display an `print()` statement and an `input()` at the same time on separated log places. I am using **Pycharm** for this project.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: whre do you want to use them? separate consoles? file? ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Output to two different consoles using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38219491/output-to-two-different-consoles-using-python)

Comment: no it does not because it does not update logs, when i make buffering 0, it gives me 'ValueError: can't have unbuffered text I/O
' this error.